# How to implement the platform independent file handling with sharing option?

Tags: c++, windows, cross-platform, ifstream, std

Legacy code having:

```
 _sopen( filepath, _O_RDONLY, _SH_DENYNO);
```

I can change it to:

```
std::ifstream file{ filepath, std::ios::in };
```

But still, its windows specific as the above statement will build through VS2019. It provides default constructor with third parameter as below (`ios_base::_Openprot` is `_SH_DENYNO`) :

```
explicit basic_ifstream(
    const char* _Filename,
    ios_base::openmode _Mode = ios_base::in,
    int _Prot = (int)ios_base::_Openprot);
```

Is there any C++ standard way to support sharing option `_SH_DENYNO`on all platform?

Comment: Nope - You'll have to make a wrapper class to use platform specific mechanisms for that and afaik, Posix only has limited support for mandatory file locking.

Comment: `_SH_DENYNO` (i.e. WinAPI read and write access sharing) is the default used by the C runtime if not otherwise specified. The C runtime only supports WinAPI delete access sharing for temporary (delete-on-close) files. Access sharing has nothing to do with processes in Windows. Actual file locking, on the other hand, is byte-range locking for a particular process and file object combination, and it has nothing to do with access sharing for `CreateFileW` and `DeleteFileW` calls. A file with byte-range locks can be deleted if delete access is shared.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/locking-and-unlocking-byte-ranges-in-files

Comment: @ErykSun `_SH_DENYNO` it provides flexibility while opening the file to other processes to access the same file. The locking of byte-range is an altogether different thing here.

Comment: The context for my comment is Ted's comment that mentioned POSIX file locking, which is per process. The equivalent in Windows is byte-range locking, which is also per-process, and in practice the byte range can be from beginning of the file to an arbitrary size beyond the current file size, so in effect it can be the entire file. I already explained the relationship between `_SH_DENYNO` and WinAPI file-access sharing (read, write, delete sharing) and that it is *not related to processes at all*. Access-sharing is strictly at the filesystem level for open file objects.